# Database Logon Error in crystal report

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I have this error in crystal report on server. This report works on developer machine.

```
"Logon failed. Details: ADO Error Code: 0x Source: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server 
 Description: [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Invalid Instance()).]Invalid connection.
 SQL State: 08001 Native Error: Error in File 
 C:\Windows\TEMP\temp_4c950a7a-9da0-4462-a806-74b3fddae638 {27458190-6D19-45D8-A8C9-     
 8386BE22C3F3}.rpt: Unable to connect: incorrect log on parameters."
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic ways to authenticate to a SQL Server, one with SQL username/password and one with "Integrated Security", or a Windows account.  The fact that you can connect locally, but not on the server leads me to believe you're using integrated security.

If you are using integrated security, the user running the web-site needs access to login (by default it's something like "NETWORK SERVICE").  You can use impersonation for this to set it to whatever user you need (Google ASP.NET impersonation).

Comment: I resolved my issue by pass the port number with server name like : <Servername>,1433

Answer (score 0):

use datasource=servername or ip address\instance name if availabel,port number

examples

```
DataSource=myservername\myinstancename,1433
DataSource=myservername,1433
DataSource=113.132.223.33,1433
DataSource=113.132.223.33\myInstancename,1433
```

default port number is 1433 or 1434

my problem is solved with this, posting for the use of others.